# OpenAPI `v3/api-docs` returns an array of ascii integers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi

When using openAPI to generate docs for the RESTful APIs, I found an issue when trying to use it.

```
Spring Boot version: 2.7.12
Spring framework version: 5.3.25
Open API version: 1.7.0
```

When not adding `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, `localhost:8080/v3/api-docs` will return an array of integers, which I'm pretty sure is the ascii code of the expected json file.

And once adding `@EnableWebMvc` annotation back, it could work, but it will also override the customized Jackson configuration inside the application.xml, so I really don't want to add `@EnableWebMvc` annotation.

Currently I can use @EnableWebMvc and override the `extendMessageConverters()` method to add the desired `ObjectMapper`, in the class which implements the `WebMvcConfigurer` interface. But it looks weird, and I'm trying to find other solutions.

Does anyone know the reason and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, the open api itself will return a byte array, and I have one generic message converter class, which will handle this type, so that the default array handler won't take affect.

Comment: So what modifications did you make? It seems I have the same problem.